# Conversion of file with iconv within R

Tags: r, iconv

I'm using Knitr and Pandoc to create a pdf document. I have a table in that document containing some diacritics.

Sample data:

```
SampleTable <- data.frame(Nazov=c("Kratkodobé záväzky (TA)","Dlhodobé záväzky 
                           (LA)","Záväzky celkovo (TA)"))
```

Create Name.Rmd file file

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, dpi=600, fig.width=12, fig.height=15}
    print(xtable(SampleTable))
```
````

Create Name.md file

```
knit("Name.Rmd")
```

Now I would like to use the R (base) iconv() function:

```
iconv(x, "ISO_8859-1", "UTF-8")
```

to convert the file to the UTF encoding.

At what point to do that? I have tried directly on that table (SampleTable) rather then the whole document (Name.Rmd or Name.md) neither worked. I have tried other couple of tricks non of them successfully.

EDIT"

```
> str(SampleTable)
  'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
  $ Nazov: Factor w/ 3 levels "Dlhodobé záväzky \n                  (LA)",..: 2 1 3

> dput(SampleTable)
  structure(list(Nazov = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Dlhodobé záväzky \n                             
  (LA)", 
 "Kratkodobé záväzky (TA)", "Záväzky celkovo (TA)"), class = "factor")), .Names =   
 "Nazov", row.names = c(NA,-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post the `dput` of "SampleTable" since the default encoding on our systems might be different than on yours.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Thanks for looking into it yet again. Much appreciated.

Comment: In fact this is @Yihui fault suggesting R based "iconv". So he is to blame :)

Comment: Sorry, but I guess `dput` doesn't preserve encoding, so unfortunately your `dput` is not very helpful. Are you using RStudio by any chance? RStudio has an option to "save with encoding" under the file menu. There, you should be able to select "UTF-8" and avoid the conversion approach that I mentioned in your other answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm using RStudio and that was the first thing I have tried, but it didn't work. I have tried now again and it works! The reason was that I didn't include the table itself into .Rmd just run the code in core R and then just using the table name to run Markdown in order to generate the .Rmd file. Thanks for pointing this out!